# For Part a) Find three possible rearrangements of the equation f(x) = 0 into the form x = F(x)

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots

Part a) 
f(x) = x^5 - 5x + 6

(I understand Decimal Search and the premise behind the iterative method of finding the root but don't understand this question at all)

Answer (score 1):

There are some iterative methods to solve equations of the form $F(x) = x$, i.e. when you have a function and want to find a fixed point of it. The problem is, the convergence of these methods, and their speeds, usually differ wildly for different $F$, even if algebraically $F_1(x) = x \iff F_2(x) = x$.

For example, we know that $F_1(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $F_2(x) = 3x - 2$ both have $1$ as a fixed point. It just might happen that a given method will work fine for $F_1$ and not work for $F_2$, or the other way around. Or a method may work for one of the $F_i$, but not at all for the other.

In your case, you have to find $F_1, F_2, F_3$ such that $F_i(x) = x \iff x^5 - 5x + 6 = 0$.